# Get Elements from a list in SoapUI Response to a Groovy list

Tags: list, groovy, response, soapui

I send a request and get a response containing a list. I have to Iterate through the element of that list, and send another request for each element in the list.

Below is a simplified example of the response. In Groovy, I need to iterate a list of "mID". How do I get them from the Response to the list in Groovy?

```
<ns:MeddelelseList>  
  <ns:Meddelelse>  
    <ns:mID>123456</ns:mID>  
  </ns:Meddelelse>  
  <ns:Meddelelse>  
    <ns:mID>234567</ns:mID>  
  </ns:Meddelelse>  
  <ns:Meddelelse>  
    <ns:mID>345678</ns:mID>  
  </ns:Meddelelse>  
  <ns:Meddelelse>  
    <ns:mID>456789</ns:mID>  
  </ns:Meddelelse>  
</ns:MeddelelseList>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll find the [XmlSlurper](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/util/XmlSlurper.html) to be useful. The example below should be enough to get started. (I removed the XML namespace and simply used text directly.)

```
def rootNode = new XmlSlurper().parseText(
'''
<MeddelelseList>  
  <Meddelelse>  
    <mID>123456</mID>  
  </Meddelelse>  
  <Meddelelse>  
    <mID>234567</mID>  
  </Meddelelse>  
  <Meddelelse>  
    <mID>345678</mID>  
  </Meddelelse>  
  <Meddelelse>  
    <mID>456789</mID>  
  </Meddelelse>  
</MeddelelseList>  
''' )

def mIDList = []    
rootNode.Meddelelse.mID.each { mID -> mIDList << mID }
mIDList.each { mID -> println mID }
```